# Failed to launch AWS Elastic Beanstalk in Tutorial

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image]

I've been trying to work my way through this [AWS Elastic Beanstalk tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html). Following it to the letter, I'm getting a consistent error message at **step #3**.

`Creating Auto Scaling group named: [xxx] failed. Reason: You have requested more instances (1) than your current instance limit of 0 allows for the specified instance type. Please visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an adjustment to this limit. Launching EC2 instance failed.`

The error message seems clear enough. I need to request an increase of my EC2 quota. However, I've done that, my quota is now at 10 EC2 instances and I've also been approved for 40 Auto Scaling Groups...

Any idea on what I'm missing? Full output attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guest you still failed because your request increase on other instance type.

First, go to your aws console > EC2 > Limit page then you can see some thing as below:

```
Running On-Demand EC2 instances     10  Request limit increase
Running On-Demand c1.medium instances    0  Request limit increase
Running On-Demand c1.xlarge instances    0  Request limit increase
Running On-Demand m3.large instances    5   Request limit increase
```

You can see my limit it 10 instances but with instance type `c1.medium` and `c1.xlarge` is 0. Only limit of `m3.large` type is 5. So you must request AWS increase your limit on exactly which instance type you want to use.

Comment: Cheers BTuan, that worked. Great error message though hey? Doesn't tell you what instance type is being requested!